# Dir sort discrepency

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that copies the contents of a folder (sourcefolder) to another (destfolder) using the following code:

```
robocopy /mt:128 /e /r:1 /w:1 /tee /log:%robolog% %sourcefolder% %destfolder%
```

I then want to generate a list of all of the files in both of these locations sorted by name. I am using the following lines to generate these lists:

```
dir /s /b /a-d /o:n %sourcefolder% > %sourcelist%
dir /s /b /a-d /o:n %destfolder% > %destlist%
```

For some reason, the lists aren't being sorted the same way. For example, the source list might look something like:

```
sourcefolder\subfolder1\text.txt  
sourcefolder\subfolder2\abc.txt  
sourcefolder\subfolder3\file.exe
```

But the destination list might look like:

```
destfolder\subfolder2\abc.txt  
destfolder\subfolder3\file.exe  
destfolder\subfolder1\text.txt
```

I can't figure out why the dir command is generating lists that aren't in the same order. I need to make sure that these list are in identical order before I move to the next part of my batch file.

Comment: `dir /s /b /a-d /o:n %destfolder% | sort > %destlist%`

Answer (score 1):

The `dir /S` command applies the specified sort order (`/O:N`) for every sub-directory individually, but it does not sort the directories. However, there is the `sort` command, which can be used here:

```
dir /B /S /A:-D /O:N "%sourcefolder%" | sort > "%sourcelist%"
dir /B /S /A:-D /O:N "%destfolder%" | sort > "%destlist%"
```

Answer (score -1):

You may prefer the results from the where command:

```dos
where/r "%sourcefolder%" *.*>"%sourcelist%"
where/r "%destfolder%" *.*>"%destlist%"
```

Comment: `where` does not force sorting, so the result is the same as for `dir` without its `/O` option...

Comment: Nobody said it does force sorting, nor did anyone ask for forced sorting. The OP asked a question that hasn't been answered. _(both their commands match so should work the same, but don't)_. I have provided an alternative command which may not exhibit the same discrepancy.

Comment: `dir` without `/O` and `where` (and also `for`,...) return the items the same order, basically depending on the file system and the entries in the file allocation tables; the OP is actually asking for a non-random order for both directories, so I am afraid `where` is definitely not a solution...

Comment: ...and there lies the answer you should have provided. We must therefore assume that source and dest are on different systems.

Comment: No, they can be on the same system; I guess the file allocation table might reflect the order in which the files have been created (at least for FAT[32]); on NTFS it is a bit more complicated... when I mentioned `dir`, `where` and `for`, I meant the same order when applied to *the same directory tree*...

Comment: I don't understand the point you're trying to make, I can assure you that running DIR or WHERE does not output records in the order they were added to the FAT or MFT. Whilst I'm happy to accept that running the results through a Sort command will enforce their order, it doesn't answer the question of what is happening, why it appears random. Every time I run the where command as in my answer above the results appear default ordered alphabetically.

Comment: My tests with `where` *seem* to suggest it sorts alphabetically but I'm not sure that means much since `dir` does that as well :-) It appears from a search that this is controlled by `FindFirstFile` behaviour which is deferred to the file system drivers. For example, FAT simply returns them in the order in which they exist in the directory "file" (where deletions can be overwritten later). It may be that NTFS sorts by name but I'm not sure - `FindFirstFile` itself does not sort.